# GlassFish web service application works fine then 404s if restarted

Tags: java, servlets, intellij-idea, glassfish, http-status-code-404

I am developing a RESTful web service application in IntelliJ idea. I am deploying it to GlassFish with a war exploded artifact. The application simply works sometimes, and doesn't other times. I can launch it, it runs fine, then stop the application, launch it again, and I get 404. Here are a list of things that seems to temporarily fix the issues (until a consequent run with the same configuration and I get another 404).

- Rebuilding the project
- Removing and re-adding the war exploded artifact
- Removing or adding libraries or dependencies
- Unchecking or checking export on dependencies
- Redeploying the application (but not restarting the server)
- Reloading the application from the admin console

GlassFish log prints out the following

`[2017-02-14T21:38:37.212-0700] [Payara 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer] [tid: _ThreadID=63 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool(2)] [timeMillis: 1487133517212] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Mapping conflict. A Servlet registration exists with same mapping as the Jersey servlet application, named launcher.MyApplication, at the servlet mapping, /*.]]`

But it does this when it runs successfully and when it fails, it doesn't seem to be related. I will research it more but have found little information on this message (perhaps because its a warning of little importance?)

I have been banging my head against this issue for a while now. I am a absolute beginner to deploying applications to servers (especially in IntelliJ), but any help or tips would be appreciated.

Thank you

**EDIT:** I have not gotten to the point where if I restart the server or redeploy enough times it works again. Anywhere from 2-5 tries and it works again with for no reason. (Seems to work more frequently when I redeploy)

Comment: Does the issue persist if the app is deployed and then redeployed manually, outside of IntelliJ IDEA, via the war while or whatever method you are using? Could it be that you have 2 instances of the app deployed by mistake, like one via default GlassFish deployment method and another via IDE? Does it happen with any project, like a new hello world web application or is it app specific? Answering these questions will help you to isolate the problem.

Comment: The issue does persist if I deploy directly from the admin console or the command line (asadmin). I don't believe there would be 2 instances running as I have no applications running in glassfish before deploying. It does seem to be app specific though, as I created a new test web application project and it seems to deploy fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like I have finally found the issue. I was missing a servlet mapping in the **web.xml** to the class in my project that subclasses Application and uses the @ApplicationPath annotation to identify the base URI for all of the JAX-RS REST resources.

```
...
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>services.MyApplication</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>services.MyApplication</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
...
```

Still unsure as to how it worked occasionally without this mapping specified, very weird. Anyway now it seems to function correctly every time.